# Change IN with JOIN to work around limit of 1000

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an oracle query to delete rows in a child table, but the query doesn't work because of too many values in the `in` clause. Is there a different way I can write this by using `join` or something to make it work?

```
delete from PROCESS 
where PACKAGE_ID in (select id from PACKAGE where NAME like 'Test%');
```

---

*Had used `*` instead of `id` in the inner select there, so when I switched to `id` it worked. But I'm still curious if this can be written in a different way, as there is a limit of 1000(?) items in an `in` clause.*

Comment: Why would this not work because of too many values? How exactly does this not work? Too slow? Errors?

Comment: Well, it didn't work because of my mistake with `*` instead of `id`. Apparently the "too many values" error I got from Oracle really should've said "too many columns". But since I have experienced "too many values" with queries created from code (no sub-select, just a bunch of ids), I assumed I would hit this limit here as well so I wondered if there was an alternative. But as others have said this limit doesn't exist for sub-selects, so the problem is gone :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit of 1000 items in an `IN` clause only applies when you "manually" specify them. It doesn't apply when the items are returned by a sub-query.

I think the way you have it now is the way to go.

Comment: Oh really? That's great! Guess I can just keep using this then.

Comment: @Svish: I suggest you do! :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
delete from 
  PROCESS 
where 
  exists(select 1 from PACKAGE where NAME like 'Test%' and id = PROCESS.id);
```

An index over `(PACKAGE.id, PACKAGE.NAME)` would be very helpful to speed up the sub-query.

Comment: An index over (Package.Name, Package.id) would be even more helpful. Prefix range scan and all...

Comment: @Thilo Whether `NAME` or `ID` is pulled first from the index - both should be equivalent (IMHO).

Comment: @Tomalek: No. We want to select all ids, filtering by a range of names. If we have an index starting with names, we get a range scan access path. The other way around, we have to scan the whole index.

Comment: @Thilo Why would it scan the whole index when the ID is fixed? (I'm not trying to prove you wrong, I'm genuinely interested)

Comment: id is not fixed. We want to select all ids from Package that match. We then take all these ids and get the Process records for them (So Process.Package_id would also be a good index to have).

Comment: The query is analogous to "get me all telephone numbers of people named Smith". You'd want to have an index sorted by name, not by number.

Comment: But I see now, that you are trying to do it the other way around (+1 for that): going through all processes first, and then looking up the package name for that. In this case, your index would be better (for the same reason: filter columns first, result columns later). Which approach is better depends on how many processes and packages there are, and how many need to be deleted.

Comment: @Thilo Right. Essentially the sub-query runs once per PROCESS and in that scenario the ID is fixed. The order of the index has implications on the sub-query performance only if the selectivity of one of the columns is vastly higher than that of the other. The most selective column should be the first in the index. It could well be that NAME is more selective than ID, in which case switching the column order would make sense. Having both columns in the index is essential so the sub-query can be satisfied with a single index seek operation (note that the sub-query does not return a value).

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a `GROUP BY`

```
delete from PROCESS 
where PACKAGE_ID in (select id from PACKAGE where NAME like 'Test%' GROUP BY id);
```

Comment: That would be equivalent to    select distinct id from PACKAGE where NAME like 'Test%'

Comment: I very much doubt that this makes a difference (Oracle should be grouping this already, and `id` sounds like it is unique anyway).

Comment: I was going to suggest `DISTINCT` but I know this isn't available in all flavours of SQL (I'm not familiar with Oracle) so I thought GROUP BY would be a safe suggestion.

Comment: Yeah, the id is already unique so grouping or distinct wouldn't help anything.

Answer (score 0):

> Had used * instead of id in the inner select there, so when I switched to id it worked.

That will not work, because it selects all columns, whereas you need just one.
If you expand the `*` you get something like the following, which makes no sense:

```
where PACKAGE_ID in (select id, something, foo, name from PACKAGE);
```

---

> But I'm still curious if this can be written in a different way, as there is a limit of 1000(?) items in an in clause.

There is no such limit for a sub-select. In fact, that should be the best way to write this query.

There is a limit (maybe 1000) for an IN *list*:

```
where id in (1,2,3,4,5)
```

Comment: Yeah, didn't hit me that the "too many values" error I got actually meant "too many columns". Figured it was because of that limit I had met before, but that was through code and query generation and not sub-selects, so this makes sense.